# Can action tags be punctuated like dialogue tags?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, dialogue

I have a habit of using action tags in the same way as dialogue tags.

Example:

> "I don't know," she said.
>
> "I think not," he scratched his chin thoughtfully.
>
> "This could have gone better," the man frowned.

vs.

> "I don't know," she said.
>
> "I think not." He scratched his chin thoughtfully.
>
> "This could have gone better." The man frowned.

See how in the first block, I've punctuated dialogue & action tags the same?

I often do that because (to me) the "soft break" of a comma makes actions feel like they're happening simultaneously with the dialogue. But I'm not sure if this punctuation is grammatically correct, or more importantly, if it's readable to others.

**Is this ever acceptable grammar in fiction?**

Comment: Do you read much fiction? What have you seen in there? At any rate, you can write any way you like; your editor/publisher might have the last word.

Comment: The second set is conventionally punctuated. It's only with verbs of saying/dialogue tags that lead into, break or follow quoted text that the comma can be used.

Comment: Thank you. Could you post that as an answer so I can mark this solved? I can answer it myself, but I'd hate to deny you the credit.

Comment: Punctuation is not grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version is nonstandard—and arguably ungrammatical.

Consider this:

> "I don't know," she said.

This is really the same as:

> She said the words "I don't know."

I added *the words* and removed the stylistic comma for emphasis—and to help better make the next point.

---

Now look at your other sentences:

> "I think not," he scratched his chin thoughtfully.
> He scratched his chin thoughtfully the words "I think not."
>
> "This could have gone better," the man frowned.
> The man frowned the words "This could have gone better."

You can *say* words, but you can't *frown* or *scratch your chin thoughtfully* words.

Unless it's some science fiction, fantasy, or horror novel where that literally *can* be done and you're making an explicit point about it. In such an edge case, it might be considered acceptable. But I wouldn't base any regular writing on that premise.

---

It's understandable if you see separate sentences as causing a break in timing that you don't like—and if you want to preserve the use of a comma within a single sentence to prevent that.

However, you can do all of that while still following normal convention and maintaining grammar:

> "I don't know," she said.
> "I think not," he said, scratching his chin thoughtfully.
> "This could have gone better," the man said, frowning.